# Dimension of a subspace with given condition

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I think that pretty quickly we can say that the dimension of this particular subspace of K^n is less than n, since we can re-write a1 = -a2 - a3 . . . - an. However, how do we know that, for example: a2 is not some multiple of a3? My approach would ideally be to construct a basis for this subspace.

Comment: You could take the basis $u_2, \cdots, u_n$ where $u_i=(-1,0\cdots,0,1,0,\cdots,0)$ with the 1 in the ith component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension is $n-1$ because you can define an isomorphism \begin{align*} A&\longrightarrow K^{n-1}\\(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)&\longmapsto(a_2,\dots,a_n)\end{align*}

Comment: I just realized that the dimension would be n-1. I haven't yet been introduced to isomorphisms, however.

Comment: It can be easily translated without isomorphisms – just a little longer to explain. Just take as a basis of $A$  the $n-1$ vectors defined as $a_1=-1,a_2=1$, all other coordinates equal to $0$, then $a_1=-1, a_3=1$, all other  coordinates equal to $0$, and so on.